# Merging Raster files in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, raster-calculator, merge, error-000840

I have six ASCII files in ArcMap 10.3 that I am trying to convert into one Raster file for the purposes of producing a linear cross-section of the height (Z) values. I have converted all six ASC files to GDB files, and also to LYR files.

However, when I try the Merge tool to create the final conjoined Raster image, I am getting the error message:

> ERROR 000840 The value is not a Table View.

as soon as I enter the first Raster file to be merged.

[image]

If this is not possible, the other possibility may be Raster Calculator, but I am unsure how to proceed with a merge here.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the merge tool is for vector data. The relevant tool is combine (ArcToolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools > Local > Combine). The required input are integer rasters, with attribute tables, and the result is a single raster containing a new value field that represents all possible combinations and attributes for each input raster with the original raster values.

If your data is continuous (floating point) this operation is not possible and really does not make sense. The new raster value, of all possible combinations, would be arbitrary and for floating point data and, potentially, combinations of every cell of every raster. If this is the case you may just want to create a raster stack, where all of the rasters are contained in a single raster file. This is how spectral data is stored and analyzed. If you are after cross-sections representing a [xy]z value the combine tool is not relevant and you should perhaps rethink your analysis/data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Another tool to combine rasters is **Mosaic To New Raster** which will merge multiple raster datasets into a new raster datasets. I use it combine multiple elevation rasters together whether they are overlapping or not. The [Mosaic method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/mosaic-operators.htm) should be looked at if the raster completely or partially overlap

Comment: I believe that the OP has overlaying (common extent) and not adjacent rasters. The mosaic tool(s) are for creating a raster composite of adjacent and not overlaying rasters. The tool for creating a multiband raster stack is "Composite Bands". If rasters overlap, the mosaic tool will apply a generalization statistic to derive new cell values in the overlapping areas and not provide unique combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to merge multiple raster files, if they don't overlap, is to use Cell Statistics. Use the raster files as input and specify Max as statistical method.